# How to filter .zip file using FilePicker in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using FilePicker plugin but it is not providing any way to filter .zip file. It shows all files but i want to show only .zip files. How to do this.

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows)

> async Task PickFile(string[] allowedTypes = null)
>
> Starts file picking and returns file data for picked file. File types
>   can be specified in order to limit files that can be selected. Note
>   that this method may throw exceptions that occured during file
>   picking.
>
> Parameter allowedTypes: Specifies one or multiple allowed types. When
>   null, all file types can be selected while picking.
>
> On Android you can specify one or more MIME types, e.g. "image/png";
>   also wild card characters can be used, e.g. "image/*".
>
> On iOS you can specify UTType constants, e.g. UTType.Image.
>
> On UWP, specify a list of extensions, like this: ".jpg", ".png".
>
> On WPF, specify strings like this: "Data type (*.ext)|*.ext", which
>   corresponds how the Windows file open dialog specifies file types.

Comment: i am doing this
string[] allowedTypes = { "*/.zip" };
FileData file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile(allowedTypes);
but it is not working

Comment: why are you including a "/"?  It appears that the filter is platform specific, so you will need to customize this per platform.

Comment: how will use allowedTypes in Android

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have done it by using string[] allowedTypes = { "application/zip" }; FileData file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile(allowedTypes);